# how to map List<ItemsList> to List<SelectItem>

Tags: java, collections

Sorry for this, i am new to java if the question is too simple. I am making a program that requires me to get items from a database, process them in Java and then load them to a select list. Can someone please help me on how to replace the items with the data from the database.

A section of the database Resultset is as follows,

```
    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    List<ItemsList> list = new ArrayList<ItemsList>();
    while (result.next()) {
        ItemsList itm = new ItemsList();
        itm.setCode(result.getInt("productcode"));
        itm.setDesc(result.getString("productname"));
        itm.setQtyStock(result.getInt("productquantity"));
        itm.setCost(result.getDouble("productprice"));
        list.add(itm);
    }
```

My SelectItems in Beans is as per below, i am looking for a way of inserting productname and productquantity from database results above. These variable are in two different columns in the database.  Example instead of hard coding sugar and 1.2, i get it from productname and quantity

```
private  shopItems selectedItem;
private static final SelectItem[] listOfItems = 
{
    new SelectItem(new shopItems("Sugar", 1.2)),
    new SelectItem(new shopItems("Flour", 0.85)),
    new SelectItem(new shopItems("Cooking Fat", 2.2)),  
};
```

Ill access this using a data-panel in JSF but i know how to do that.
 Thank you, i appreciate your help.

Comment: In JSF2 there is no need to convert everything to `SelectItem`. Just use your list with a converter

Comment: Thank you @BalusC , do you have such example anywhere online? If have only used converters to convert integer to double.